# Using resourceBundle with an external file, java

Tags: java, multilingual

I have been reading other questions and answers around this but I am not getting how resource boundle works for completly.
I think it is similar at Joomla way of using multilingual options.
Basically you have files for the different messages you want to read for different languages.
So I created System.properties inside my src/Lang folder
Inside I create

```
STARTING_MYAPP=Starting my app
```

I might be wrong here, but anyways I am not able to read the default file.  Right now I am brain death, and I cant make sense of anything I read
this is how I am doing this

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
String basename ="System";
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename, locale);
System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString("STARTING_MYAPP"));
//UserPreferences UserPrefs = new UserPreferences();
```

when I call getBundle(),it has two inputs, the basename and the locale, right. I am having trouble with the basename. If my file is inside src/lang/System.properties, how should I look for it.  basename="System", basename="Lang/System", basename="System.properties", basename="myProject.label".

I tried all of this and some more combinations but non work, I always get something like
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name System, locale en_US

About the locale, how I leave it up to default, so I dont have to use a System_en_US.properties or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basename is structured like a fully qualified class name (because resource bundles can be classes), so if your classpath root is `src` and the resource is a file `src/lang/System.properties`, then the basename is `lang.System`.

> About the locale, how I leave it up to
>   default, so I dont have to use a
>   System_en_US.properties or something
>   like that.

Simply use the [`getBundle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String)) method that takes only the basename.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class ResourceBundleTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String basename ="lang/System";
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename, locale);
        System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString("STARTING_MYAPP"));
    }
}
```

In the src/lang folder I created a file named System.properties that contains...

```
STARTING_MYAPP=Starting my app
```

The output is: Starting my app

[This page](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/intl/datamgmt/loading.html) explains how the JDK resolves the ResourceBundle names.

Comment: yes it works, i must be tired it was my fault. I misplaced the file