# ResourceBundle file not found, properties file not in jar

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

About the resourcebundle errors, I've read other questions about the same subject, but I didn't get any wiser. Tried different things, doesn't help. To give a little background: I developed a small app (JDK6), that does some flat file parsing and editing automatically. The app starts by reading some data from a properties file.

**Important**: 
I want to be able to change the properties file. I don't want to put it in the jar file.

However, even with the little example app that I tried creating, based on another questions/answer [here][1]:

```
package restestapp;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class ResourceBundleTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String basename ="myresource";
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename, locale);
        System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString("STARTING_MYAPP"));
    }
}
```

Both files are here:

```
/home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp/ResTestApp.jar
/home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp/myresource.properties
```

or even

```
c:/temp/ResTestApp.jar
c:/temp/myresource.properties
```

But when I run it, it gives me this output:

```
dakoina@ubuntu:~/Documents/ResTestapp$ java -cp /home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp/ -jar "ResTestApp.jar"
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name myresource, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1539)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1278)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:805)
    at restestapp.ResTestApp.main(ResTestApp.java:19)
```

and in Windows, the same...

```
c:\temp>java -jar ResTestApp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle
 for base name myresource, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at restestapp.ResTestApp.main(ResTestApp.java:19)
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742158/using-resourcebundle-with-an-external-file-java
```

I can't see where I am wrong :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-jar` means: compose the classpath from the given jar and from all the ones it references in its manifest. So the `-cp` option is ignored.

Your command line should be:

```
java -cp /home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp;/home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp/ResTestApp.jar the.main.Class
```

That said, a resource bundle is used to load internationalized labels. If you just want to read properties, you'd bette use the `java.util.Properties` class.

Comment: 'java -cp /home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp:/home/dakoina/Documents/ResTestapp/ResTestApp.jar ResTestApp.class' doesnt seem to work. Main class not found...

Comment: Your class is named `restestapp.ResourceBundleTester`. Not `ResTestApp`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, actually I copied over the original code and forgot to change my new class name (_ResTestApp_)

Comment: I understand that you can use either Properties or ResourceBundle. I believe there is no efficiency gain or anything of using Properties instead of ResourceBundle. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not just about efficiency (although Properties will be faster: ResourceBundle uses Properties behind the scenes). It's just that Properties is used to read Properties from a Properties file. ResourceBundle is used to read internationalized values from a set of properties files and from a hierarchy of locales.

Answer (score 2):

`myresource.properties` [needs to be in classpath for jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

put this properties file into jar and configure classpath (as described in the link)

Comment: java -classpath c:/temp/ -jar ResTestApp.jar
Like this? If so, that doesn't work :/

Comment: please see the command as @JB has described, or include it in your jar file and set classpath

Comment: sorry, but I couldnt put the properties file in the jar

Comment: Sure, for future reference :)